# When can you earn more by selling a losing security and buying it back at lower price?

Tags: capital-loss

My goal is just to maximize capital gain on stocks and options, regardless of [Wash Sale Rule](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/washsalerule.asp) or tax.  My grandparents live in Canada. I'm not trying to sell to minimize taxes. I quote one example below.

> [[u/WillTradeBTCforPizza
>    comments at the top.]](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/cc0kao/autist_in_my_discord_yolod_7k_into_200k/etjp3m0/) The volume says the earliest he could have bought these was on Friday 7/5 or Monday 7/8, when they were trading from $2.36-$0.98. They closed at $.06 yesterday.
>   ​
>
> So in about a week he vaporized $7k, had the balls let them go to expiration, and in a freak miracle earns 1/5 of a million dollars.
>
> [[u/randominternetguy3 asks](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/cc0kao/autist_in_my_discord_yolod_7k_into_200k/etjs6qn/)] **Rather than riding down and back up, wouldn't the smarter move be to pick them up for \$300 at the bottom?** Shit, he could have doubled down and made \$400k lmao
>
> [[u/prodoubt]](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/cc0kao/autist_in_my_discord_yolod_7k_into_200k/etjta2q/) Yes. But no one would ever cut losses and then reinvest into that same strike - unless they knew something. This is why the SEC won’t invrstigate further if they even look at this. This is truly just the luckiest shit ever happening to someone who fucked up days ago not cutting losses at 40 or even 70% down.
>
> [[u/randominternetguy3]](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/cc0kao/autist_in_my_discord_yolod_7k_into_200k/etjtqxn/) Right. But that's kind of the point - if you're willing to ride it to zero, shouldn't you also be willing to double down?
>
> [[u/prodoubt]](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/cc0kao/autist_in_my_discord_yolod_7k_into_200k/etjuhax/) Which is why I said he would only do that if he actually knew something. Or maybe he was playing 5D space chess and his plan all along was to make this look like he is stupid af by not cutting losses, but deep down knew his lotto was coming.
>
> I am going to wager on dumb luck.

Comment: Not sure what your grandparents have to do with this.  It's kind of obvious that if you buy low and sell high that you make money.  The same holds true  if you're an investor in the stock and you sell at a loss and you are forunate enough to buy back lower, your profit potential is higher than the guy who just rode it down and back up.  The problem is that if you book your loss and the stock doesn't drop more, you've missed the train.  The wash sale is meaningless (USA) in terms of P&L  You don't lose the loss, you just have to defer it.

Answer (score 2):

To take your question literally, you can profit by selling when 1) the stock continues to drop and 2) the stock rises after you re-buy. Neither of those are guaranteed.

What you've posted is some "random internet guy" on Reddit saying you should have bought when it hit the bottom. Profound hindsight... The problem is that you don't know what the bottom is to know when to buy.

Comment: Thanks. I posted more from that Reddit thread for context. Does the context change your answer?

Comment: Not really - without knowing the full context it sounds like luck. There's not a specific "strategy" I know of to sell low and buy lower.

Comment: It's a bit afield from conventional investing and a bit of a different scenario from the OP's premise but with an income portfolio comprised of say preferred stocks, it can make sense to book a loss and buy something else from the same issuer with the higher yield.  This opportunity occurs when an issue craters, making its yield  more attractive than that of the initial position.  Same money remains invested but higher yield obtained. Obviously this is  execution of both legs at current price rather than the chance lucky timing of buying back at a lower price later.